# Tensorflow Object Detection - export_inference_graph.py - Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [44] rhs shape= [360]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I trained the a object detection model with 11 classes (0=base + 10 actual classes) using main_model.py. Afterwards I want to export the inference graph use export_inference_graph.py. I am using exactly the same pipeline_config_path as for training and the trained_checkpoint_prefix parameter refers to the model.ckpt I have trained. I receive the error below:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [44] rhs shape= [360]
 [[Node: save/Assign_526 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](SecondStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases, save/RestoreV2:526)]]
```

labelmap: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1isVO81rbYRGNrSboUd_DQh03DOxWV5is/view?usp=sharing

config file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vFkKbU5cytWMJwyt7tztLPxAnQ_bVnNo/view?usp=sharing

Python: 3.6.2
Tensorflow: 1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Your labelmap and configs are gone. Please make sure your num_classes=11 instead of 90.